# ckeditor deteles page <title></title> title

Tags: ckeditor, metadata, title

I'm trying to set the meta information of a page in ckeditor.
This works fine, except of the title. Everything I write in here, will be deleted by ckeditor if I change to WYSIWYG mode and back to source.

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: Have you seen [this sample](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fullpage.html)?

Comment: I already tried this. But then CKEditor adds all the not needed stuff like html, head, body...

Comment: Could you please enlighten me, as how would you like to edit `<title>` without `<head>` and `<body>`?