# CKEditor deletes content between <title></title> tags

Tags: html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

After a few days of searching and trying to solve, got nowhere.

CKEditor 4.7.0 is stripping the content between the `<title></title>` tags. **I need CKEDitor to leave the title content alone no matter how / where the title tag is used.**

I have tried:

- allowedContent: true,
- extraAllowedContent : 'title',
- extraAllowedContent: 'title[*]',
- config.allowedContent = true; (in config.js)
- CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['title'] = false; (in config.js)

No luck with above. Then tried suggestion here [ckeditor deteles page <title></title> title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424303/ckeditor-deteles-page-title-title-title) which works, but I end up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OK Title</title>
</head>
<body>&nbsp;</body>
</html>
<p><br />
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><meta name="description" content="Web template presented with pure css."><meta name="keywords" content="css template"></p>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="red.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!-- Header -->
<header class="w3-container w3-theme w3-padding" id="myHeader">
<div class="w3-center">
<h4>BEAUTIFUL RESPONSIVE WEB SITES</h4>
```

What I am doing is pasting into CKEditor an example CSS templates from https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_black&stacked=h

I understand this is not the way standard HTML should be displayed (not to spec), but I need to prevent CKEditor from modifying the title tag no matter, just ignore it and let me use it wherever:) This is just a simple project for classroom where no one sees source of page and I need title tag to show in browser tab when I project page on whiteboard for students.

**UPDATE:** did discover if I save with the source in view, CKEditor does not modify the title tag. Works this way but not when in visual mode which like to have:)

Answer (score 2):

After what seemed like endless searches found some info on a drupal forum. Had so many links open lost track of exact site where obtained the info, sorry.

Solved the problem by adding the following to my config.js in CKEditor 4.7.0:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.protectedSource.push(/<title>[\s\S]*?<\/title>/gi); // allow content between <title></title>
```

Hope ***this*** will help someone else:)